# How to calculate the occurence of substring in dictionary values?

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I need to calculate the occurrences of a motif (including overlaps) in sequences (motif is passed in the first line of standard input and the sequences in subsequent lines). The sequence name starts with >, and after whitespace is just a comment about the sequence that needs to be neglected.  The input of program is like:

```
  AT
  >seq1 Comment......
  AGGTATA
  TGGCGCC
  >seq2 Comment.....
  GGCCGGCGC
```

The output should be:

```
   seq1: 2
   seq2: 0
```

I decided to save the first line as a motif, strip the comment from sequence name, join lines of sequence in one line and save sequence names (keys) and sequences (values) in a dictionary. I also wrote a function for motif_count and want to call it on dictionary values and then save it in a separate dictionary for final output. Can I do it or is there a better way?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys

sequence = sys.stdin.readlines()
motif = sequence[0]
d = {}
temp_genename = None
temp_sequence = None

def motif_count(m, s):
    count = 0
    next_pos = -1
    while True:

        next_pos = s.find(m, next_pos + 1)

    if next_pos < 0:
        break
count += 1
return count 

if sequence[1][0] != '>':

   print("ERROR")

exit(1)

for line in sequence[1:]:

    if line[0] == '>':

       temp_genename = line.split(' ')[0].strip()
       temp_sequence = ""

    else:

       temp_sequence += line.strip()

d[temp_genename] = temp_sequence

for value in d:
   motif_count(motif, value)
```

Comment: `GGCCGGCGC` has no `AT` hence seq2 is 0! Correct @DariObukhova

Comment: Obviously. Therefore, the output of function of motif_count invoked on seq2 will be 0. However, my problem is how to call out my function on dictionary keys and save its output as values for another dictionary..

Comment: can you show your dictionary

Comment: Please, refer to the code above. My dictionary is d with temp_genename as keys and temp_sequence as values.

Comment: When I try to call out the function on dictionary value the output is just:      <function motif_count at 0x10bca0488>
<function motif_count at 0x10bca0488>
<function motif_count at 0x10bca0488>
<function motif_count at 0x10bca0488>
<function motif_count at 0x10bca0488>
<function motif_count at 0x10bca0488>
<function motif_count at 0x10bca0488>

Comment: your post is a bit of a mess to be honest, the indentations are not properly formatted so you should fix that and try to provide an example of your `sequence` variable.

Comment: Sequence is provided by a user in this format:                                                           AT
>seq1 適当な配列だけど AT が行の折り目と重なっている
AGGTATA
TGGCGCC
>seq2 GC リッチな配列
GGCCGGCGC

Comment: That is not the variable, I can clearly see that it is not a list as in the code!

Comment: @SuperKogito, However, I don't know how long the user output is going to be (not necessarily 4 lines as in the example above), therefore i am using sys.stdin.readlines() method to save user's input in 'sequence' variable. The first line of user's input is always a motif, then lines starting with '>' are the sequence names. Therefore one sequence lies between two subsequent '>' characters.

Comment: yes but that is not the question, we realize that you cannot judge the length of the output but having sequence as a list (which is what you are using in your code), would help the rest of us judge the possible manipulations of the data.

Comment: @SuperKogito, I am not sure if I understood you correctly but the example of user's input to this program is like:       AT(first line) >seq 1 Comment.... (2nd line) AGGTATA (3rd line) TGGCGCC (4th line) >seq2 Comment ...(3rd line) GGCCGGCGC  (4th line)

Comment: Take a look at the comment under my answer. That should show you how to apply your function on your dict elements.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193042/discussion-between-dari-obukhova-and-superkogito).

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code by using dictionary and string expressions to get the relevant key words that you need for your processing. Assuming your sequence values are consistent and similar to what you provided, you can split over the redundant `This sequence is from` and then later filter the `uppercase` letters and finally compute the occurrence of your motif. This can be done as in the following:

```py
def motif_count(motif, key):
    d[key] = d[key].count(motif)

sequence = """AT
>seq1 This sequence is from bacterial genome
AGGTATA
TGGCGCC
>seq2 This sequence is rich is CG
GGCCGGCGC""".split('\n')

d = {}
# print error if format is wrong
if sequence[1][0] != '>':
    print("ERROR")

else: 
    seq  = "".join(sequence).split('>')[1:]
    func = lambda line: line.split(' This sequence is ')
    d    = dict((func(line)[0], ''.join([c for c in func(line)[1] if c.isupper()]))
                 for line in seq)

    motif = sequence[0]
    # replace seq with its count
    for key in d:
       motif_count(motif, key)

    # print output
    print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'seq1': 2, 'seq2': 0}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. However, this is not exactly what I need. The problem for me is how to call out my motif_count function on dictionary values --> replace value with output of motif_count --> output as lines in format (sequence name -- number of motifs).

Comment: if you take a close look at how my `motif_count(motif, key)` behaves and the way I am calling it here `for key in d:  motif_count(motif, key)`  you will realize, that this is exactly what you are asking for.